# Get the class of java.util.Arrays$ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, jakarta-ee, arraylist

How can I know the instance of `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`. I've tried this code snippet but it does not work at all :

```
if (myList instanceof Arrays) {
    //Do something here.
}
```

I have compared the object classtype with ArrayList and I had the same issue. But while I was inspecting the object, the classType was a :

```
class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
```

The conditional statement below was the only solution I found:

```
else if (myList.getClass().toString().equals("class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList")) {
    //do something here
}
```

but I think that controlling the object type by using instanceof would be a great solution.

My question is : what is the classType of `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`, so I can use **instanceof** for my control.

Thanks in advance,

Omar.

Comment: `instanceof java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: Why do you need to know at all that a class is an instance of `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`? Your code shouldn't depend on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` is a **private** inner class of `Arrays`, returned by the `Arrays.asList` method.

Since it's a private class there is no way to get access to the class in a way that it can be used with the `instanceof` operator. You can do this check using reflection however:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("java.util.Arrays$ArrayList");
// ...
clazz.isAssignableFrom(myList)
```

But I do not recommend doing that. It's a good practice [to program against an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface). In this case the [`List`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) interface defines the behavior of the object. **The actual class of the object shouldn't matter.**

Comment: Thanks for your help I didn't know that in the case of **ClassA$ClassB** ClassB is a private inner class of ClassA.

Answer (score 3):

in case the list comes from `Arrays#asList`, the returned ArrayList is NOT `java.util.ArrayList`, therefore a comparison to this class will always fail.

The question is, why do you need to know that it is exactly this implementation ? Maybe it is enough to check for `java.util.List` ?

In general it is questionable why you need the instanceof operator at all, often there are other design solutions better.

Comment: It's because of the nature of the project I'm working on. I receive a Arrays.asList() list and I couldn't change it since I'm not working on this part of the project. At last, the solution was to ask the person who works on creating the list to send me a java.util.ArrayList and it worked! Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: you can also simply wrap the retrieved list in a new list and then you can work with that further

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using `Arrays` ? You must use `ArrayList` like in this code

```
if (myList instanceof ArrayList) {
    //Do something here.
}
```